# Mail attachment in eml sent from Thunderbird not opening in MS Outlook

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, mail

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Thunderbird Mail client 13.0.1 , but when I am sending some mail attachment in .eml format, its not opening in MS Outlook in Windows? 
Though through Ubuntu 11.04 it is working fine... can anyone please help.